# Finding the sum of a recursively defined function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let f(n) be a function defined as such: $ f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}, f(3) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} $  etc. 
Basically, $ f(x+1) = f(x) + \frac{1}{x+1} $

Does there exist a formula or any efficient method to calculate or approximate the sum $ S = \sum_{x = 1}^{n} f(x) $

where n is a positive integer greater than 1?

Comment: In your sum $1$ is added $n$ times $1/2$ is added $n-1$ etc. so the sum is equal to $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n-i+1}{i}=(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}-n$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you define your sequence to be $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{1}{n+1}$, where $a_1 = 1$, we can define the partial sum, $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$.

Let $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n H_n$$
$$S_n =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{-k+n+1}{k}$$
$$S_n = (n+1)*H_n - n$$

And you can compute $H_n$ by computing the integral:
$$H_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx$$

Comment: Yeah, I know that but, my sum is a more complicated than that

Comment: @raylin in what way exactly?

Comment: What I mean is Sn doesn't equal to Hn

Comment: $ H_3 = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} $ where as $ S_3 = (1) + (1 + \frac{1}{2}) + (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}) $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77832/discussion-between-ray-lin-and-rb612).

Comment: @raylin I have corrected my answer after the misunderstanding.